# mysql exception incorrect integer value : '@column' for column from asp.net web application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i am trying to update a table created using mysql database from an ASP.NET Web page. While inserting data into table from web page
 ***mysqlexception : incorrect integer value :'@Age' for column Age at row 1*** this exception occurs.

i tried not using single quotes around column name in query but that too not working in that case ***Age cannot be null exception is occurring***

here is the code snippet for DML query i am using :

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into personal(PAN,PName,Age)values('@PAN','@PName','@Age')",con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAN",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= panBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=nameBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age",MySqlDbType.Int32).Value=Convert.ToInt32(ageBox.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
```

i am a beginner can someone help me with the situation?

Comment: Remove single quotes they go around strings

Comment: The parameter placeholder should not be enclosed in quotes. In this way they becomes literal strings and are not recognized anymore

Comment: i have already done that in that case age cannot be null exception is occuring.

Comment: @Steve i know that quotes should not be there but without them age cannot be null exception is occurring....

Comment: use DBNull.value, if there's no value for @Age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors.

First one: The parameters placeholder shouldn't be enclosed in single quotes. Otherwise they becomes literal strings and are not recognized anymore

Second one: AddWithValue takes two parameters. The first one is the name of the parameter, the second one is the value not the database type.

```
  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"Insert into personal(PAN,PName,Age)
                                       values(@PAN,@PName,@Age)",con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAN",panBox.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PName", nameBox.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age",Convert.ToInt32(ageBox.Text));
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Of course this is at risk of throwing an exception if the `ageBox` is empty. I don't know your requirements but if the Age field is required to be a valid number then a bit of error checking could be added to prevent banal errors.

```
 int ageValue;
 if(!Int32.TryParse(ageBox.Text, out ageValue))
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid value for Age!");
     return;
 }
 .... insert code follows...
```

Comment: i have tried what u mentioned but again dts not working. column in table is an integer with constraint cannot be null. when i tried your answer following trace appeared on page.

Comment: i have tried what you mentioned but following trace appeared.MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Column 'Age' cannot be null at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.OpenPacket() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadResult(UInt64& affectedRows, Int64& lastInsertId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetResultSet() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at ...

Comment: That's really strange. There is no reason for this message at this point in code. ageBox should contain a number and that number is passed to the parameter used to set the Age column. Did you try with the debugger to see what values are passed in the parameters collection?

Comment: yes i have tried debugger values are correct in parameter collection even ageValue is turning to be correct this exception occurs at cmd.executenonquery() call. something happens as openpacket(). i m using visual studio 2010 and its a simple ASP.NET Application.

Comment: No idea. Just for a check. If your remove the NOT NULL on the Age field, what happens? Works and the record is inserted correctly or not?. Another one, what version of MySql and what version of the connector?

Comment: when i tried same code with varchar type column without any constraint in table code runs fine so is type INT and constraint are the reason or what............rily confused...

Comment: when i removed NOT NULL Constraint it worked fine........can you specify the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: No, it should work if there is a value in the `@Age`