# how an integer gets stored in MYSQL database when we input it using webpage textbox control?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

While working on an application i came across a strange situation where, when i tried inserting value into a MYSQL database ***column*** having constraint ***Not Null*** using a textbox on webPage of ASP.NET application .Exception saying ***'ColumnName' cannot be null*** occurred every time. Can anyone tell me the reason behind this strange behavior.

You can refer to the code in:
[mysql exception incorrect integer value : '@column' for column from asp.net web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307566/mysql-exception-incorrect-integer-value-column-for-column-from-asp-net-web)

Comment: well, don't insert a null value. but since you don't show us any of your actual db interface code, we can't really help.

Comment: Subject and description of the question do not seem to match.  Do you want to know how an integer gets stored, or how to deal with a non-nullable field?

Comment: Not Null constraint means the value for the column cannot be null, see if you are setting the value to null explicitly anywhere in your code.

Comment: I think it's the same code as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307566/mysql-exception-incorrect-integer-value-column-for-column-from-asp-net-web

Comment: Is there a different field that is marked as "Not Null"?